# Cannot get fields of child nested class who have abstract parent

Tags: java, oop

When trying to get field values of child nested static class, getting `null`. *1 *Each class file divided by horizontal line. How to retrieve the values of child Warrior?

---

```
abstract class GameCahracter{

        public String name;

    public String type;

    public Weapon weapon; 

    public int hitPoints;

    public String getDescription(){

        return type + "; " + name + "; " + hitPoints + " hp; " + weapon.type; 
    }

    public static class Warrior extends Player{

        public final String type = "Warrior";

        public int hitPoints = 100;

        public static final  Weapon.Sword weapon = new Weapon.Sword(); 

    }
}
```

---

```
abstract class Player extends GameCahracter {

}
```

---

```
GameCahracter.Warrior wr = new GameCahracter.Warrior();

wr.name = "Joe";

System.out.println( wr.getDescription());
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
null; Joe; 0 hp; null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't re-declare the member variables. Instead you should set the values inside the constructor.

```
public static class Warrior extends Player{
    public Warrior() {
      type = "Warrior";
      hitPoints = 100;
      weapon = new Weapon.Sword(); 
    }
}
```

Another option would be to create a `GameCahracter` constructor that takes arguments that match each of the member variables.

As a side note: public member variables are a bad idea.

Comment: *public member variables are a bad idea.*. Do you mean I should define *Warrior* class as private? If so then how can I access it?

Comment: @RCola: You can make getter/setter methods to provide access as needed. This allows you to keep the API of the class to stay the same even if you change the way the class is internally structured. Using methods instead of public members also allows you to validate input. Currently anyone could set `hitPoints` to 1000 or -1000.

Answer (score 1):

`GameCahracter.name` and `GameCahracter.hitPoints`  were not assigned, so they remain null. `Warrior.name` and `WarriorhitPoints.hitPoints` were assigned, but they are different fields. It is a bad idea to have fields with the same name in parent and child (unlike methods).